# How scientists know which particle is/is not influenced by strong force?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, strong-force

Muon is said to be uninfluenced by strong force, unlike pion.

My question is, based on which experiment, scientists determine a particle is influenced by strong force or not?

Edited:
Thank you for the answer. However, I still don't know based on which conditions, a particle is said to be influenced by strong force? Particle Physicist did a lot of experiments over 65 years, yes, but to determine which conditions?

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, based on which experiment, scientists determine a particle is influenced by strong force or not?

It is not *one* experiment, but *a large number* of experiments, the data studied by thousands of people, and the results  published in peer reviewed journals of physics.

These data at present have been mathematically fitted with what is the [Standard Model of particle physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model).

The results are gathered  by the [Particle Data Group](https://My%20question%20is,%20based%20on%20which%20experiment,%20scientists%20determine%20a%20particle%20is%20influenced%20by%20strong%20force%20or%20not?).

For the muon , the production and decay experimental data early on necessitated  the hypothesis of a weak interaction and no strong interactions, which fact is incorporated in the SM.

New particles when discovered are studied and their strong or weak interactions behavior is decided according to  their production and decay behavior when the data are fitted with the SM mathematical model.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I still don't know based on which conditions, a particle is said to be influenced by strong force? Scientists did a lot of experiments, yes, but to determine which conditions?

Comment: @MarkLevis it is not "influence". At the level of particles it is called interaction, and the elementary particles in the table https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZvTV.png have a definition and their interactions are shown if you click on the table in the wiki link. The composites of these elementary particles will have the interactions of their component elementary particles. The experiments were done to determine the behavior in scattering and decay of particles, and the existence of the particles in the table developed slowly to the SM from the fit of  theory to the data.

Answer (score 1):

@annav is correct (as usual). 65 years of particle accelerator tests have shown which particles are dominated by electromagnetic forces and which are dominated by the strong and the weak forces. A truly huge body of knowledge has been accumulated on this topic, which would represent several years' worth of upper division and graduate course material in atomic and nuclear physics.

Your work is thus cut out for you.

Comment: My question was very specific. You said "65 years of particle accelerator tests have shown which particles are dominated by electromagnetic forces and which are dominated by the strong and the weak forces", then please elaborate which one show that a particle is/is not dominated by strong force, i.e in case of Muon. Otherwise, your answer add nothing to my question

Comment: The answer to your question would constitute a review of 65 years of experimentation and as such would run to hundreds of pages of text. Suggest you find a textbook on the strong force and prepare for some very, very difficult mathematics.